# PHP Active Record Memcached

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

How to use phpactiverecord memcached? anyone can help me?

```
$database = array(
    'connection' => 'local',

    'local' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/database?charset=utf8',

    'server' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/database?charset=utf8',

    'memcache' => 'memcache://localhost:11211'
);

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($config) use ($database) {
    $config->set_connections($database);
    $config->set_default_connection($database['connection']);
    $config->set_cache($database['memcache'], array('namespace' => 'My', 'expire' => 120));
});
```

As default i get admin data from admin model like this

```
use My\Admin;
use ActiveRecord\Model;

class Admin extends Model {
    static $table_name = 'web_admin';
}

print_r(Admin::all());
```

So, how to set admin data into memcached and how to get that data?

Answer (score 1):

Their documentation doesn't explain anything about how to use caching but their [github](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Model.php#L159) link says that you can do it just by setting cache variable to TRUE.
So you will need to set.

`static $cache = TRUE;`

in the models for which you want to cache the queries.